# regex find characters between " "

Tags: regex

How can I match all characters between 2 specified characters, say `" "` ->
from `sdfsf " 12asdf " sdf`

I want to get `12asdf` only.

Comment: What were you hoping to get? Is it not returning the leading whitespace? Show us the regex you are using and put your example results in a code block, please.

Answer (score 96):

You can use the following pattern to get everything between `" "`, including the leading and trailing white spaces:

```
"(.*?)"
```

or

```
"([^"]*)"
```

If you want to capture everything between the " " excluding the leading and trailing white spaces you can do:

```
"\s*(.*?)\s*"
```

or

```
"\s*([^"]*)\s*"
```

Comment: Agreed. Make sure to look up anything you can find on "non-greedy" (vs. "greedy") expressions. Should be an interesting read if you don't know it yet. And it will surely make your life with regexes easier if you know the difference.

Comment: Through my testing these actually don't get the inner characters excluding the quotations, like the question asked. These do however include the quotations too!

Comment: Like others have said, this doesn't answer the question, it gets the text WITH the quotes.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you use

```
(?<=")(?:\\.|[^"\\])*(?=")
```

This will match only what is between the quotes (not the quotes themselves) and also handle escaped quotes inside your string correctly.

So in `"She said, \"Hi!\""`, it will match `She said, \"Hi!\"`.

If you're using JavaScript or Ruby (which you didn't mention) and therefore can't use lookbehind, use

```
"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"
```

and work with the capturing group no. 1.

Comment: @Don: Can you provide the link to the non-working regex (click on Save regex and post that link)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match(/"([^"]*)"/,$input,$matches);`. `$matches[1]` will have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^"].*[^"]
```

If you enter: "Elie", it will give Elie (note: without quotes)