# c# using regex to parse string between quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I'm fairly new and I couldn't get this to work properly.

I have this string

> ["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7","string8","string9","string10"]

And I want to get all values between the "

I think regex would be best to do the task.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this line coming from a file?

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402797/regex-find-characters-between http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697644/regex-match-text-in-between-delimiters

Comment: Is it a bird? Is it a plane? Whatever it is, it's not a string.

Comment: Who knows? It could an array of strings. @Simon Whitehead has taken a punt in his answer on it being a single string that is missing the enlosing quotes, and missing \" for the embedded quotes.

Comment: Maybe you can use JavaScriptSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will capture between the quotes:

```
(?<=")[\w]+(?!=")
```

An expanded example:

```
string s = "[\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\",\"string4\",\"string5\",\"string6\",\"string7\",\"string8\",\"string9\",\"string10\"]";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "(?<=\")[\\w]+(?!=\")")) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: OP, this is a better answer than the spliting version.

Comment: @RyanCopley could you explain why you think it's better than splitting the string? IMO using a regex for simple string manipulation like this is overkill. It's also more effecient to use a split than it is to use a regex...

Comment: Efficiency is debatable for a single use scenario.. but then we are speculating :) I hope it helped in some way anyway :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead True, however, a regex should be used for *matching* data, not parsing.

Comment: Could you please improve it so it also works with spaces within the quotes?

Comment: Just add \\s after \\w in the regex

Answer (score 3):

Since this looks like JSON, try using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337495) class

```
string myString = "[\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\",\"string4\",\"string5\",\"string6\",\"string7\",\"string8\",\"string9\",\"string10\"]";

string[] strings = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<string[]>(myString);

foreach (string str in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Kinda seems overkill though.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a job for `Split` rather than just Regex:

```
string str = "[\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\",\"string4\",\"string5\",\"string6\",\"string7\",\"string8\",\"string9\",\"string10\"]";
Regex rgx = new Regex("[\\[\\]\"]"); // get rid of the quotes and braces
str = rgx.Replace(str,""); 
string [] split = str.Split(','); // split on commas. that's it.

foreach (string s in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This requires no special matching regex that you may to change if your quoted strings get messy. Consequently, it is (again, in my opinion) more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a CSV string e.g.

```
"\"string1\", \"string2\", \"string3\""
```

Then you don't need a regex for something as trivial as this, you could use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) with a sprinkle of LINQ:

```
var values = csvString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Replace("\"", "").Trim());
```

Comment: you won't be able to do this if the quoted string contains a comma.

Comment: @alltej I didn't say it was a universal solution, it was one that would work for the given sample data :)