# Exchange powershell search-mailbox searchquery parameter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Okay, so this seems like a silly question, but I can't seem to find anything about it. I've checked in the [AQS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512.aspx) and haven't seen anything about it yet either. So I'm trying to conduct a search on the subject line of all mailboxes in my organization with a query like this:

```
foreach ($db in $mdblist) {Get-Mailbox -Database $db -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'subject:"Monthly Expences Report" AND attachment:"Report_######.doc"' -LogOnly -LogLevel FULL -TargetMailbox joseph.c.larrew -TargetFolder Searches\1003333 |
```

Both the subject parameter and attachment parameter are literal strings and I did mean to spell "expences" that way.

I can do a search for just the subject and a separate search for the attachment and both give positive results, but when I "AND" them, no results. I've done a search against a specific mailbox that I know should come up with a positive and still no dice. Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402797/regex-find-characters-between

Comment: I don't think you can use regexes in the searchquery parameter...

Comment: You can't. Are you 100% sure that there is an overlap between messages that have that subject AND has the named attachment?

Comment: 100%. I sent one to another user and searched his mailbox specifically as well.