# R Regex to identify and replace characters between multiple dots

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have the following codes

```
"ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL"
"XYZ.Z.SVN.11.12.111.99.ASDDL"
```

and I need to replace the characters that exist between the 2nd and the 3rd dot. In this case it is `SVN` but it may well be any combination of between `A` and `ZZZ`, so really the only way to make this work is by using the dots.

The required outcome would be:

```
"ABC.A..10.10.390.10.UDGGL"
"XYZ.Z..11.12.111.99.ASDDL"
```

I tried variants of `grep("^.+(\\.\\).$", "ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL")` but I get an error.

Some examples of what I have tried with no success :

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402797/regex-find-characters-between)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498843/regex-to-pickout-some-text-between-parenthesis)

**EDIT**

I tried @Onyambu 's first method and I ran into a variant which I had not accounted for: `"ABC.A.AB11.1.12.112.1123.UDGGL"`. In the replacement part, I also have numeric values. The desired outcome is `"ABC.A..1.12.112.1123.UDGGL"` and I get it using `sub("\\.\\w+.\\B.",".",x)` per the second part of his answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRlchWUPJ0clZz1EvOMxPz9AAhIwtwVSoi7u7j5KOglJEZJReFETeUM/QCEga6lla6jkGu7j4KGlyFZcmaSjFadhbRcfpxWrFxOhpVhvVxsR4g7kg/UBcoaNQkFqUYxui@f8/AA)

```
x <- c("ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL", "XYZ.Z.SVN.11.12.111.99.ASDDL")
sub("^(?:[^.]*\\.){2}\\K[^.]*", "", x, perl=T)
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:[^.]*\.){2}` Match the following exactly twice

  - `[^.]*\.` Match any character except `.` any number of times, followed by `.`
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the pattern. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[^.]*` Match any character except `.` any number of times

Results in `[1] "ABC.A..10.10.390.10.UDGGL" "XYZ.Z..11.12.111.99.ASDDL"`

Comment: This answer is the one I used as it is easier for me, as a non-expert in regex . I can also customize where `{2}` with the exactly twice element.

Answer (score 2):

```
x= "ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL" "XYZ.Z.SVN.11.12.111.99.ASDDL" 
sub("([A-Z]+)(\\.\\d+)","\\2",x)

[1] "ABC.A..10.10.390.10.UDGGL" "XYZ.Z..11.12.111.99.ASDDL"
```

- `([A-Z]+)` Capture any word that has the characters A-Z
- `(\\.\\d+)` The captured word above, must be followed with a dot ie`\\.`.This dot is then followed by numbers ie `\\d+`. This completes the capture.

so far the captured part of the string `"ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL"` is `SVN.10` since this is the part that matches the regular expression. But this part was captured as `SVN` and `.10`. we do a backreference ie replace the whole `SVN.10` with the 2nd part `.10`

Another logic that will work:

```
sub("\\.\\w+.\\B.",".",x)
[1] "ABC.A..10.10.390.10.UDGGL" "XYZ.Z..11.12.111.99.ASDDL"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly regex but here is one more approach

```
#DATA
S = c("ABC.A.SVN.10.10.390.10.UDGGL", "XYZ.Z.SVN.11.12.111.99.ASDDL")

sapply(X = S,
       FUN = function(str){
           ind = unlist(gregexpr("\\.", str))[2:3]
           paste(c(substring(str, 1, ind[1]),
                   "SUBSTITUTION",
                   substring(str, ind[2], )), collapse = "")
       },
       USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "ABC.A.SUBSTITUTION.10.10.390.10.UDGGL" "XYZ.Z.SUBSTITUTION.11.12.111.99.ASDDL"
```